# Extract Email-id from Linkedin using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pdfkit
import time
from pdfrw import PdfWriter

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankurkhandelwal1/')
time.sleep(40)
soup= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for div in soup.select('.pv-contact-info__ci-container'):
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
        href=link.get('href')
        print(href)
```

I want to print only mobile No. and Email id of user, but it prints so many unnecessary line. how to do for fetching exactly email and Mobile No?

Comment: Scrapy is good for crawling pages. It also has a parser that can match a regex and save it to a file.

Comment: @alex So how can i eliminate it?

Comment: @JayPratapPandey could you write a sample output that your code gives.

Comment: @cmertayak:#skip-link
mailto:a11y-feedback@lin
/mynetwork/
https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankurkhandelwal1
tel:9015833773
mailto:ankur281993@gmail.com
/in/mudit-mishra-96210a38/
/in/sagar-bansal-a4a40597/
/in/harish-kumar-49b4b9b2/
/in/daphnis-labs-a78b3b13a/
/in/deveesh-mehandiratta/
/in/ravi-sharma-772a831a/
/in/silky-kalra-kohli-46b5a3140/
/in/shiv-pratap-singh-0a162b113/
/in/kanishka-goyal-01099b97/
/in/himanshu-tiwari-8a7ba351/
/psettings/presence